# Anchor tag not poining towards the exact url?

Tags: asp.net, anchor, repeater

I am using `repeater` control in my web page.I am using an `anchor` tag and an `image` within the repeater.The idea is when the page loads the image and corresponding URL should be loaded from the database.

The problem is when i point the cursor on the image,instead of exact URL the URL is combined with the project name.

For example the URL i should get is `www.facebook.com`,but what i am getting is
`localhost:64396/CMS/www.facebook.com`

The repeater control i have used is furnished below

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_img_footer" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <a href="<%#Eval("IMAGE_URL") %>"><img alt="<%#Eval("IMAGE_NAME") %>"
        src="<%#Eval("IMAGE_PATH") %>" width="32px" height="33px" /></a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: You should include the protocol in the src attribute as well, try it with http :// in front : http : // www.facebook.com instead of just www.facebook.com. Otherwise it'll be src definition relative to the path of the page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the protocol in the src attribute as well, try it with http:// in front : http://www.facebook.com instead of just www.facebook.com.
Otherwise it'll be src definition relative to the path of the page itself.